# Authenticate user using omniauth and Facebook for a rails API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth

I'm building a Rails API and have successfully built a way for a user to authenticate using Omniauth Identity.

We simply post to auth/identity/callback from the client, passing in an auth_key and password.
The server then returns a doorkeeper token that the users then uses from then on to access the app and identify themselves.

This diagram illustrates this:

[image: Client server relationship]

We'd now like to implement a Facebook login from the client, but are having trouble making it work, both theoretically and practically.

On a simple Rails App with Omniauth Identity, you'd simply call auth/facebook, but if we put a link from this in the client, it calls the server and the server then logs:

`INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.`

The app is set up correctly in Facebook with an ID and Secret, so perhaps the log-in prompt is getting returned to the server?

I'm getting confused though chaining the authentication.  Any help gratefully appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `omniauth-facebook` gem?  https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that for the authentication. I've implemented it fine in a simple Rails -> Facebook app.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question but the oauth chain goes like this: client -> your server -> facebook's server -> client -> facebook's server -> your server. How is your API implemented? Does the client have a web interface?

Comment: Yep - the client is an Angular app, the server is a Rails API.  I know I could do it easily if the authentication was taking place on my server, but I can't get my head around it.  Ideally the UX flow would be user visits client, clicks 'Log in through Facebook', this then verifies their creds with Facebook, and then my server responds with a token for them to browse the protected API.

Comment: Yep, that would be the simpler flow, but that's just not how Omniauth works. Maybe you shouldn't use Omniauth and take a look at Facebook's Client-Side Authentication. Or maybe try to combine both. You should check out this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication

Comment: What did you end up doing here? I was wondering about the same thing....

Comment: Also wondering what you ended up using

Comment: I've been stuck in this for a while, so I've made it completely manual... Once you obtain the authorization code plug it into this... And it should work... It's not tested extensively so if you had any comments please add them.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

the best way I found (after being stuck for a while on this issue ) is to do your omniauth2 (specifically in my case using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/) angular plugin) manually...

I'll discuss the solution for Facebook as it was my case, but everything could apply to any other provider.

first you have to know how omniauth2 works ([as documented for humans here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer#-login-with-oauth-20))...

1. **Client:** Open a popup window for user to authenticate.
2. **Client:** Sign in (if necessary), then authorize the application.
3. **Client:** After successful authorization, the popup is redirected back to your app. with the `code` **(authorization code)** query string parameter

*the redirect back url must match your front-end app url not the back-end url and it must be specified in your facebook app configurations*

4. **Client:** The `code` parameter is sent back to the parent window that opened the popup.
5. **Client:** Parent window closes the popup and sends a `POST` request to `backend/auth/facebook` with `code` parameter.
6. **Server:** `code` (**Authorization code**) is exchanged for [`access token`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

*here is described in details how to exchange the `code` for an `access-token` from [facebook developers documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#confirm)*

7. **Server:** use the `access-token` retrieved in step **6** to retrieve the User's info.
8. VOILA you've got yourself a user you can merge/create account for/link with other oauth providers/etc. but bear in mind that user can revoke some of the permissions (like **email**, facebook supports revoking some of the permissions)...

---

(enough talking, show me some code)

First you have to add HTTParty gem to your Gemfile

```
gem 'httparty'  # Makes http fun again (http client)
```

I've added [this gist](https://gist.github.com/a14m/a60714f968e1178f0717) which contains the flow for step (6, 7 and 8) those are the most problematic steps and are not documented almost anywhere.

the gist exports 2 main methods:

```
Omniauth::Facebook.authenticate(authorization_code)
```

which is used to authenticate the user with facebook and return the user_info, long_live_access_token (valid for 60 days)

```
Omniauth::Facebook.deauthorize(access_token)
```

which is used to de-authorize/revoke the access_token and application permissions on facebook...

This is used for special requirement I have, when the user revoke the email permission requested on facebook login... we revoke the whole application permissions... this will prompt the user in the next login as if it's his first login ( no need to go to facebook apps and manually revoke the application)...

here is how it's used in the controller

```
user_info, access_token = Omniauth::Facebook.authenticate(params['code'])
if user_info['email'].blank?
  Omniauth::Facebook.deauthorize(access_token)
end
```

---

That's it... now if you are interested in the internals of the implementation... here is the code as seen in the gist. (added for reference)
Feel free to fork it, edit it, help making it better.

```
require 'httparty'

module Omniauth
  class Facebook
    include HTTParty

    # The base uri for facebook graph API
    base_uri 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3'

    # Used to authenticate app with facebook user
    # Usage
    #   Omniauth::Facebook.authenticate('authorization_code')
    # Flow
    #   Retrieve access_token from authorization_code
    #   Retrieve User_Info hash from access_token
    def self.authenticate(code)
      provider = self.new
      access_token = provider.get_access_token(code)
      user_info    = provider.get_user_profile(access_token)
      return user_info, access_token
    end

    # Used to revoke the application permissions and login if a user
    # revoked some of the mandatory permissions required by the application
    # like the email
    # Usage
    #    Omniauth::Facebook.deauthorize(access_token)
    # Flow
    #   Send DELETE /me/permissions?access_token=XXX
    def self.deauthorize(access_token)
      options  = { query: { access_token: access_token } }
      response = self.delete('/me/permissions', options)

      # Something went wrong most propably beacuse of the connection.
      unless response.success?
        Rails.logger.error 'Omniauth::Facebook.deauthorize Failed'
        fail Omniauth::ResponseError, 'errors.auth.facebook.deauthorization'
      end
      response.parsed_response
    end

    def get_access_token(code)
      response = self.class.get('/oauth/access_token', query(code))

      # Something went wrong either wrong configuration or connection
      unless response.success?
        Rails.logger.error 'Omniauth::Facebook.get_access_token Failed'
        fail Omniauth::ResponseError, 'errors.auth.facebook.access_token'
      end
      response.parsed_response['access_token']
    end

    def get_user_profile(access_token)
      options = { query: { access_token: access_token } }
      response = self.class.get('/me', options)

      # Something went wrong most propably beacuse of the connection.
      unless response.success?
        Rails.logger.error 'Omniauth::Facebook.get_user_profile Failed'
        fail Omniauth::ResponseError, 'errors.auth.facebook.user_profile'
      end
      response.parsed_response
    end


    private

    # access_token required params
    # https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#confirm
    def query(code)
      {
        query: {
          # The authorization_code we want to exchange for the access_token
          code: code,
          # This must match the redirectUrl registerd in the facebook app.
          # You can save it to ENV['WEB_APP_URL'] if you have multiple facebook apps for development and testing
          # so you can support testing app on development and production app on production env.
          redirect_uri: "http://localhost:9000/",
          client_id: ENV['FB_APP_ID'], # Facebook appId
          client_secret: ENV['FB_APP_SECRET'], # Facebook app secret (must not exist on front-end app for security)
        }
      }
    end
  end
end
```

here is another [nodejs tutorial implementing oauth for instagram](https://hackhands.com/building-instagram-clone-angularjs-satellizer-nodejs-mongodb/) that helped me understand how oauth2 is working (added for reference)

Comment: I've been looking for something like this for hours, thank you!

Comment: I'm stuck with this as well. Just to be clear: what you have implemented is not using the omniauth-facebook and omniauth gems at all? Or is any of their functionality required?

Comment: no, it doesn't require anything except 'http-party' gem

Comment: ok. so my API would get the code and use your methods to get the user data from FB (including FB uid and access token). So far it makes sense. But once I have this data, I would have to manually login / create user in my User model, correct? Only using uid / access_token vs usual email/password pair? I am using Devise and usually Omniauth handles this. is it ok to just login / create a User in my User model? The fact that I got a CODE in my API lets me assume this is an authenticated user? I'm starting to figure out the flow in my mind but would appreciate confirmation I am on the right track

Comment: yeah I guess so... check how devise omniauth works (cause I don't think it handles the creation of the user automatically... you have to do it yourself) reference: `def self.from_omniauth(auth)` here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

and you are free to decide the criteria for logging the user.. yourself (if you don't want to use uid)

Comment: gist is not available anymore, also Omniauth::Facebook class doesn't seem to be connected anyhow to omniauth gem? Its doesn't look like omniauth 'strategy'. Or it was designed for standalone usage only?

Comment: I've fixed the link to the gist (thanks)... and yeah it's implemented as a standalone class (not as omniauth strategy)... it's actually have nothing to do with the omniauth gem (just named the class this way to work in my internal implementation... just namespaced it this way... you can change it)
It has a dependency on 'httparty' though (but you can implement it without any dependency using the standard library)

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue the best resource I found is the rails example application in the satellizer github repo : https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/ruby

Your satellizer code calls the [AuthController.authenticate](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/ruby/app/controllers/auth_controller.rb#L34) method. This method uses the [oauth model classes for each provider](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/ruby/app/models/oauth) to convert the code you receive into an access token. Then in your [user class](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/blob/master/examples/server/ruby/app/models/user.rb) you can retrieve the user that match the info you got from the provider.

At the end the controller method returns the jwt token to the client.

In my case the controller part is a bit different because I also use devise for mail/password authentication but I copy th oauth classes as is and it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

To communication with facebook api. I recommend use ['omniauth-facebook' gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook). You can clone this example to understand more: https://github.com/ralphos/omniauth-facebook-example

Comment: This will work for a straight app (and I have used it in the past, a great Gem). From what I see though it can't be used for an API, unless I'm missing something?  See my comments above from months ago.

Comment: please elaborate on how to integrate omniauth gem with api-based app.